# Jquery slimjet event delegation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegation, jquery-events

again I have huge problem.
First thing I use Slimjet Web Browser with Tampermonkey for chrome.
I can't use in script `$('.class:first')` or `$('.class:contains(...)')` etc becouse always I get error

> TypeError: V[g].exec is not a function

Someone know why?

Now I'm trying to add to div with specific class link which do something after click on it. I try everything but event fires only once if it works...

```
var collapse1 = $('<center>')
    .html($('<a>')
    .attr('id', 'alli1')
    .attr('href', '#')
    .text("Kliknij tutaj aby rozwinąć opis"));

$('.clan-desc').first().html(collapse1);

$($('.clan-desc').get(0)).on('click', '#alli1', function(event) {
  if ($(this).text() === "Kliknij tutaj aby rozwinąć opis") {
    $('.clan-desc').first().html(alliance_txt1).append(this);
    $(this).text("Kliknij tutaj aby zwinąć opis");
  } else {
    $(this).text("Kliknij tutaj aby rozwinąć opis");
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

When I doing like this I have same error like up. Ofc I tried to 
`$($('.clan-desc').first()).on('click', '#alli1', function(event){...});`
or
`$(document).on('click', '#alli1', function(event){...});`
Always the same error.

Comment: ofc $('.clan-desc') exists on page. There are 2 div with the same class, without id's.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function handler(event){
            if ($('#alli1').text()==="Kliknij tutaj aby zwinąć opis"){
                $('.clan-desc').first().html('').append(collapse1);
                $('#alli1').text("Kliknij tutaj aby rozwinąć opis");
            }else{
                $('.clan-desc').first().html(alliance_txt1).append(collapse1);
                $('#alli1').text("Kliknij tutaj aby zwinąć opis");
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        var collapse1 = $('<center>').html($('<a>').attr('id', 'alli1').attr('href',    '#').text("Kliknij tutaj aby rozwinąć opis"));
        $('.clan-desc').first().html('').append(function(){
        return collapse1;   
        }).on('click', handler);
```

I tried to make something like this. It works but I want to:
    `.on('click', '#alli1', handler);`